# Ecler NUO 2 mixer connected to MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, music

I have maybe a silly question here. I have "Ecler NUO 2" mixer (and obviously turntables with it as well) and would like to ask you if it is anyhow possible to connect it to my "Mac" so as I would not need turntables (I know that it is possible to do so with "Serato Scratch Live" but it is not very practical)?

---

> Ecler NUO 2 Features
>
> Compact DJ Mixer. 2+1 channels, 6 inputs, isolator switches,
>   adjustable VCA crossfader, balanced XLR output.
>
> -3 channels, 8 inputs (2 PHONO, 2 L-LINE, 3 H-LINE, 1 MIC)
>   -2 independent outs (OUT 1, OUT 2, REC)
>   -VCA Crossfader (ECLER PRO Fader, 4,000,000 operations)
>   -3 band EQ (LO-MID-HI)
>   -ISOLATOR switches
>   -Adjustable curve x-fader
>   -Adjustable curve upfaders
>   -PFL monitoring system
>   -VU meter monitoring
>   -Effects loop with PRE/POST fader functions
>   -Internal oversized switching power supply ±18V

From: http://www.djbooth.net/index/dj-equipment/review/ecler-nuo-2/

---

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of inputs does a "Ecler NUO 2" have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: not without additional hardware.

To control [Serato Scratch Live](http://serato.com/scratchlive), you have to feed your computer some specially encoded signals from some special LPs that they produce. You need to buy Scratch Live, two or more of their special LPs (one for each deck) and then a special box like the [Rane SL 2 for Scratch Live](http://serato.com/scratchlive/rane-sl2) that sits between your mixer's mains output and your computer. This box converts the analog signal from the mixer (which, with the special Scratch Live LPs is *not* something you should try to listen to -- it's not human-friendly and can damage your speakers and hearing) in to a digital signal that Scratch Live uses to match the playback of audio on the computer, to the rotation of the LPs on your decks.